# How to allow sass file path in Rails Chrome browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, sass

I start create new Rails app and can't understand why there is no path to sass files. How to allow sass file path in Rails Chrome browser?

[image]

like that
[image]

Here is my Gemfile

```
gem 'bourbon'
gem 'neat'

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :development do
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.14'
end
```